# for the following system to be consistent what must k not equal to

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$−3x+5y+7z=7$
$−3x-7y+kx=8$
$15x+23y-19z=-40 $

by using echolon form I got to this

\begin{bmatrix}
       -3 & -7 & k & 8           \\[0.3em]
       0 & -12           & 5k-19 & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0           & 0 & -4k + 12 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}

but not sure how to get to K not equal to?
K can be only one number.

Comment: I'm putting you a question in order to help you: What does it mean for a system to be consistent?

Comment: Are you sure it's $kx$ and not $kz$ in the second equation?

Comment: @abiessu You're mixing things up, "k can be only one number" and "the system is consistent" are 2 different things.

Comment: @wild-squirrel: thank you, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps if you rewrite your reduced echolon form as a system of linear equations:

$$\begin{align*}
-3x-7y+kz&=8\\
-12y+(5k-19)z&=0\\
(-4k+12)z&=1
\end{align*}$$

Now start solving your system from bottom to top. Be careful not to divide by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the last row in your reduced echelon form. We cannot have an equation that is of the form $0x+0y+0z=1$, the system would be *inconsistent*. So what value of $k$ would make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be wiser and easier to apply Cramer's rule to solve this problem.

Cramer's rule says: **Iff $\Delta \neq 0$ then the system of linear equation is consistent**

So we just need to find $\Delta \neq 0$, where $\Delta$ is the determinant of the system. This system consists 3 linear equation and 3 variables so $\Delta$ will be determinant of third order. So we have:

$$\Delta = \begin{vmatrix}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i
 \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
  -3 & 5 & 7 \\
  -3 & -7 & k \\
  15 & 23 & -19
 \end{vmatrix}$$

Now we'll just simplify it to three determinants of second order.

$$\Delta = -3\begin{vmatrix}
  -7 & k \\
  23 & -19
 \end{vmatrix}
 - 5\begin{vmatrix}
  -3 & k \\
  15 & -19
 \end{vmatrix}
+ 7\begin{vmatrix}
  -3 & -7 \\
  15 & 23
 \end{vmatrix}$$

$$\Delta = (-3)(-7)(-19) - (-3)23k - 5(-3)(-19) + 75k + 161(-3) - 105(-7)$$

$$\Delta = 144k - 432$$

Now we set $\Delta \neq 0$

$$\Delta = 144k - 432 \neq 0 \implies 144k \neq 432 \implies k \neq 3$$

So if $k \neq 3$ the system is consistent, otherwise it has infinite amount of solution or it doesn't have, depending on $\Delta_x, \Delta_y, \Delta_z$